# How to convert normal text into date format in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell, date

I want to convert it from

Format 1: 12272019(this is just a number)

To

Format 2: 2019-12-27

I tried using below:
date -d '12272019' +%Y-%m-%d

But it is showing invalid date format

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On OS/X, `date` is quite a bit different, so you can specify the input format for `date`:

```
date -jf "%m%d%Y" 12272019 +"%Y-%m-%d"
# => 2019-12-27
```

Linux does not allow you to do that though, but you can do it easily with `sed`:

```
echo 12272019 | sed -e 's/\(..\)\(..\)\(....\)/\3-\1-\2/'
# => 2019-12-27
```

Answer (score 3):

The `date` command only accepts a predefined set of formats for its input. Your format `mmddyyyy` is  not part of that set.

You can re-arrange your date string manually using either `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(..)(..)(....)/\3-\1-\2/' <<< 12272019
```

or `bash`:

```
date=12272019
echo "${date:4}-${date:0:2}-${date:2:2}"
```